# How do I fix xamarin.ios app crash on launch in iPhone 8 cellular data?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have develop a xamarin.ios app thats work fine on all iPhone and iPad except iPhone 8. Its crashed on launch in  iPhone 8 on cellular data. Its working good on wifi. I don’t have iPhone 8 device right now, so I am checking it on simulator. But simulator using wifi and its working good on simulator. How can I identify the problem and how to solve it? 
FYI we are consuming a service on app launch that need an active internet. Any idea, Please reply.

Comment: Possibly, app is not able to find rootviewcontroller at launch, I would first provide a rootviewcontroller then do a network operation

Comment: Actually my app need to check service very first. We have enabled cellular data but its crashed in iPhone 8 only. When we connect to wifi its work in iPhone 8 also. app working good in another iPhone with cellular data.

Comment: What does crash log say?

Comment: We don't have iPhone 8 right now, So we are unable to check crash log. Any other option to check on simulator?

Comment: Crash would log something in application output like sigabrt or index not found something

Comment: Actually we are not getting this crash till now because we are using other iPhone or simulator and its working good at my end. But client told me that issue in iPhone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are checking on IPv6 network but our API was not compatible to IPv6. When we change the network to IPv4, Its work perfectly. But as per apple guidelines we must have to compatible our API to **IPv6 network**.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment, but I don't have the reputation for one.

Without knowing what is happening when your app has launched, have you tried testing your app without a Wi-Fi or data connection?

The issue might be that your clients device is getting a different response from the service that you have not accounted for and this might be causing exceptions etc.